# Exchange server 2010 on c#

Tags: c#, exchange-server

I'm trying to perform an email migration from exchange 2003 to office 365.  However in order to to that I need to create an object of type `ExchangeConnectionSettings` which comes from `Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Storage.Management.ExchagneConnectionSettings`.  However I don't know where to get that from.  Could anyone please help me.  thanks,

Comment: Can you elaborate on your scenario? Where are you scripting this and what are you trying to script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.data.storage.management.exchangeconnectionsettings%28v=exchg.140%29.aspx) it's in `microsoft.exchange.data.storage.dll` in the **Exchange Server 2010 SP1 Management Shell SDK**

Comment: You need to link to the documentation connected to the SDK for Exchange 2003.